# Write a ReadableStream image to file

Tags: node.js, file-io

I've been trying different things all day, but nothing seems to offer a simple, straight-forward way to write a `ReadableStream` (which is an image) to a file. I'm calling an API which returns a `ReadableStream`, but what then? I tried digging into the object a bit more, and followed it all the way to returning a `Buffer[]`, which seems like it should be what needs to go into a `fs.writeFile()` but nothing works. The file gets created but I try to open the image and it says it can't open that file type (which file type they're talking about, I have no idea).

Here is my code that returns a `Buffer[]`. I can also cut off some of those chains to only return the `ReadableStream` body, but then that returns a `PullThrough` and I am already so lost. Very little about that class online. Any suggestions?

Here is the api I'm using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cognitiveservices-computervision/computervisionclient?view=azure-node-latest#generatethumbnail-number--number--string--computervisionclientgeneratethumbnailoptionalparams--servicecallback-void--

```
  // Image of a dog.
  const dogURL = 'https://moderatorsampleimages.blob.core.windows.net/samples/sample16.png';
  await computerVisionClient.generateThumbnail(100, 100, dogURL, { smartCropping: true } )
      .then((thumbResponse) => {
        console.log(thumbResponse.readableStreamBody.readableBuffer.head.data)
        fs.writeFile("thumb.jpg", thumbResponse.readableStreamBody.readableBuffer.head.data, "binary", (err) => {
          console.log('Thumbnail saved')
          if (err) throw err
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally found a solution. I don't understand `pipe()` all that well, but when it's called from a `ReadableStream` with a filepath as parameter, it works.

The API response `thumbResponse.readableStreamBody` was the `ReadableStream`. So anyone who has a readable stream can use this solution. No need to call an API for anything.

```
  // Image of a dog.
  const dogURL = 'https://moderatorsampleimages.blob.core.windows.net/samples/sample16.png';
  await computerVisionClient.generateThumbnail(100, 100, dogURL, { smartCropping: true } )
      .then((thumbResponse) => {
        const destination = fs.createWriteStream("thumb.png")
        thumbResponse.readableStreamBody.pipe(destination)
        console.log('Thumbnail saved')
      })
```